# How to populate checkbox with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that receives the following JSON from a server

```
{"d":[
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"ACCOUNTING"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"AHOFFMAN"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"AMONROY"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"APATENTAS "},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"WRAMOS    "}
]}
```

From the array `d` in this data I need to create checkboxes, each corresponding to an element of the array, defined by the `operators` property of each element. I need these checkboxes to be dynamically generated with JavaScript/jQuery once the data is received. How can this be done?

Comment: I suppose you loop over the resulting array, create a checkbox element and add to the div or whatever location you want those to appear on the page. Have you written any code to try this yet?

Comment: You'll need to provide some mock up of your DOM structure. For example, do you intend to have a checkbox for each "operators" value? ¿Would it make sense to map each operator to an Id, or a given operator could show up more than once?

Comment: I want to have checkbox for each operators value or for each record. It's fine if same operator name comes more then once. Is it possible for you to provide sample: how to loop through JSON array and create checkbox with value.

Comment: Submitted an edit, I think it will clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var input=//get input json
var data=input.d;
for(var x in data){
    var type=data[x].__type;
    var ops=data[x].operators;
    var id="checkbox-"+ops+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
    $("<div><label></label><input/></div>")
        .children().eq(1)
            .attr({
                "type":"checkbox",
                "name":"insert here", 
                "data-type":type, 
                "data-operators":ops,
                "id":id,
                "class": "your checkbox class here"
             })
             .click(function(){ /////////////////////////// updated here
                 if($(this).prop("checked")){
                     // do action for checked event
                 } else {
                     // do action for unchecked event
                 }
             })
        .parent()
        .children().eq(0)
             .attr("for", id)
             .text("whatever label you want")
        .parent()
        .appendTo($("container you want to put them in"));
}
```

Comment: You should definitely go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over JSON result and create checkbox element and add it to div. Use jquery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop JSON. Try this:

```
   var json = {"d":[
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"ACCOUNTING"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"AHOFFMAN"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"AMONROY"},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"APATENTAS "},
    {"__type":"Service1.Operators:#MobileWCFService","operators":"WRAMOS    "}
]};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $grouplist = $('#checkboxes');
        $.each(json.d, function() {
            $('<label>'+this.operators+': </label><input type=checkbox 
              value='+this.operators+'/>').appendTo($grouplist);
        });
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kJJP8/)**

Comment: What is this from, 2005? HTML4/5/XHTML standards say all tag attributes must be in quotes.

Comment: Not trying to be offensive or anything, just current standards say...

Comment: Wow thanks. Making me write this beautifully formatted completely standards-compliant answer and then selecting this non-formatted non-standards-compliant one. Just thanks

Comment: @ZoveGames: Dude above mentioned solution is the way to solve OP whole problem. This is not the whole way/full code to solve issue. And moreover you can create html elements using jquery without quotes. It will render with quotes in browser. Anyway thanks bro :)

Comment: Is it possible to add event listener to above solution? Checkbox.check event..??

Comment: @user3461408 Updated my answer in case you need it.